# Disable alert javascript function on Flex 4 AIR HTMLLoader

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, air, alert

In my AIR application in Flex 4, I use **mx:HTML**, and when I navigate to a location like this

```
html.location = 'http://www.somesite.com';
```

But, some websites have "alert" function in javascript like this :

```
alert('hello world!');
```

and AIR show the message in a box...

I just want to remove, or ignore these messages, but I don't know how...

I think the solution is to extend the **HTMLLoader** class, but my experience in Flex is too poor..

Someone can help me ?

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best thing I could find:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e74.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e72

It looks like you can extend the HTMLLoader as you suggested and override javascript callbacks. I haven't tried this so I'm not sure but it's worth giving it a whirl.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, right we can override some javascript functions, but adobe give the list :
window.status
window.document.title
window.location
window.blur()
window.close()
window.focus()
window.moveBy()
window.moveTo()
window.open()
window.resizeBy()
window.resizeTo()

Unfortunately, Alert function is not on the list... I don't know how to do!

Comment: The idea could be to replace the native alert function like this : http://jsfiddle.net/77QEQ/5/ 
But how can I inject some code into a mx:HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

After debug and test, I found that the *HTMLLoader* has a property *window*. This *window* is like javascript DOM window.

You can use following code to disable *alert*.

```
public class MyHTMLLoader extends HTMLLoader
{
    override public function MyHTMLLoader()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(Event.HTML_DOM_INITIALIZE, htmlDomInitializedHandler);
    }

    protected function htmlDomInitializedHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        window.alert = function(){};
    }
}
```

And modify your HTML component property *htmlLoaderFactory* to ...

```
<mx:HTML htmlLoaderFactory="{new ClassFactory(MyHTMLLoader)}" ...
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but this do not work for me. I try to load this URL http://jsfiddle.net/77QEQ/ but its still display the alert message box. Dunno why because your solutions sounds to be the right way !

Comment: And it's strange, because when I debug this, the debugger pass into the htmlDomInitializedHandler function, but it doesn't override the alert... so strange

Comment: I looked that page, and I knew what going wrong. That page use _iframe_ tag inserted another DOM, that makes the frame _window_ is new one, it's not the root window, so the window.alert function not override.
I've done some research, found that we can use javascript to access child window object, window.document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow. But I not found the way to disable all child windows function. 
If your HTML component is only for one site, you can do some hack for that site.